# Select text after a tag using Xpath

Tags: html, xpath

My html is formatted something like this:

```
<pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                              <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a><hr><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"> <a href="/mathworks/devel/sandbox/henryqi/">Parent Directory</a>                                       -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="convobot-main/">convobot-main/</a>                    2022-01-27 13:55    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="matlab/">matlab/</a>                           2022-01-31 11:58    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="test/">test/</a>                             2022-01-27 13:52    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="test3%20-%20Copy/">test3 - Copy/</a>                     2022-02-09 15:09    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="test3/">test3/</a>                            2022-02-09 10:47    -
<img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="Quadractic.mlx">Quadractic.mlx</a>                    2022-01-21 15:02  3.3K
</pre>
```

I am unsure on how I can get the dates that come after the img with alt = "[DIR]". I understand that I can get the projects' names by using `'//img[@alt="[DIR]"]/following-sibling::a[1]/@href'` but I am not sure how to get the dates because it iss't contained by tags. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `//img[@alt="[DIR]"]/following-sibling::text()`?

Comment: I tried that but it also  took the `alt="[]" `one as well. It also returned a bunch of empty strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by JaSON, you should use the following XPath:

```xml
//img[@alt="[DIR]"]/following-sibling::text()
```

Or this

```xml
//img[@alt="[DIR]"]/following-sibling::a/text()
```

The only difference between the text attribute value and any other attribute value is that all the regular attributes are referenced with `@attributeName` like `@href` or `@alt` while text attribute value is referenced with `text()`
**UPD**
Previously I couldn't see the entire XML structure.
Please try this:

```xml
//img[@alt='[DIR]']/following-sibling::a/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: I tried both ways and it didn't quite give what I wanted exactly. For the first one, I got a bunch of empty string and the text for the img with `alt="[]"`. The second method got the text of the <a> tag

Comment: I see...  please try the updated answer